# How to disable animation when popover dismiss on Ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

I need to disable the fade animation when popover dismiss.

I've tried doing solutions on ionic 2 but i think ionic 4 does have a different popover.
I've already looked at ionic 4 documentation https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover. But adding leaveAnimation: undefined or null on popover creation doesn't solve the problem

```
      component: PopoverComponent,
      event: ev,
      translucent: true,
      leaveAnimation: undefined,
      componentProps: { buttons: ['Edit', 'Delete'] }
    });
```

I expect no fade animation when popover dismiss

Comment: user property: `animated: false`.

Comment: It worked. But what if only the dismiss animation is needed to be disabled and not the present animation

Comment: user `enterAnimation` property for this.

Comment: I'm new to angular animations... Can you give me some code to assign on enterAnimation property? Tnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `leaveAnimation: popoverLeaveAnimation`

```
export function popoverLeaveAnimation(Anim: Animation, base: HTMLElement): Promise<Animation> {

    return Promise.resolve(new Anim());

}
```